# Automate copy Mobile App Builds from DropBox and install to Device

Tags: android, ios, dropbox, device

Existing procedure to install iOS:-

1. Download binary from Dropbox
2. Open the application with iTunes
3. Click Install

Existing procedure to install Android:-

1. Download binary from Dropbox
2. Copy apk into device via USB.
3. Go to My Files and a appropriate folder.
4. Click on the apk and install it.

I want to transfer .apk (android app) or .ipa (iOS app) file to multiple devices and install it simultaneously. How would I do that?

Comment: Dropbox api, download it and launch intent to install it?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Is there sample avail. So that i can know, how to proceed  it.

Answer (score 3):

For Android - Assuming you sync the APKs folder to your PC/Laptop this should be easy.
You can use `ADB install -r apk-file-path` command to push and install the APK from the dropbox folder to your device(s).

If you have multiple devices connected, you need to add a `-s` paramter to the command and specify the device serial id.
To list all the connected devices, use `ADB devices` command.

Answer (score 0):

Muzikant's answer looks like it would work for Android. For iOS you should check out the [Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12). If that's too bulky for you, [PhoneGap](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy) is pretty useful as well.

This would change your current iOS procedure to be:

1. Ensure that Dropbox is synced to a folder on your PC
2. You could add a daemon to watch for changes to the folder which would then launch a script that calls
3. $ ios-deploy -r -b your.app

You can find all iOS devices on your system by following the steps found [here](http://javierhz.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-get-udid-of-iphone-using-shell.html)